Compact set covered by closed balls with positive radii
Let $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ be a compact subset. Suppose that it is covered by a collection of closed disks with positive radii. Is there a finite subcover?

What have you tried so far?

@CyclotomicField I thought about increasing the radii of the closed disks by $\epsilon$ to get finite subcover, but I couldn't go any further...

The difference between an open cover and a closed cover is in the boundary points. See if you can find a counterexample using this idea.

@CyclotomicField I can't... Can you give me more hint?

Here is a counter example. Let $K = \{x\in R^2 \ |\ ||x||_2 \leq 1\}$, denoted by $B(0,1)$, where $B(x,r)$ has center $x$ and radius $r$ and is a closed disk. $K$ has a cover $\{B(0,r) | 0 < r < 1 \} \cup \{ 
B(x,1) | ||x||_2 = 2\} $.
Note that the boundary of $K$ is covered point by point, so it does not have a finite subcover.

I suppose you can take $K={x:|x|_2=1}$ to avoid the balls $B(0,r), $0<r<1$.

@geetha290krm, you are right!

Do you know  if there is a counter-example in the case of $\mathbb R$?

@geetha290krm, a closed disk in $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed interval $B(x,r)$. Assume $K ={0} \cup {1/n, n \in \mathbb{N}+ } \subset \mathbb{R}$, then it is compact (closed and bounded). $K$ is covered by $[-1, 0] \cup { [1/(n+1), 1/n],  n \in \mathbb{N}+ }$, which can not have a finite cover.

Thanks a lot, Functor!
